# About Casting in a Class property in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, class, dynamic, casting

Is it possible to cast a sting in a class property?
what i want to do is that from 'My' class i can fetch the Form's Text properties. but for every form i have to provide the form name statically. I want to do it dyanamically. What i tried is here

```
    Dim frmName As New Object
    frmName = Name.ToString()

    Dim frmProperty As String

    frmProperty = "My.Forms." & frmName & ".Text"

    frmNameLabelControl.Text = frmProperty
```

but at the Front-End it displays 'My.Forms.Form1.Text'

Comment: I don't think you understand what a cast is. They are not magic. The word is used in the same context as "to cast something in a different light". A cast doesn't change something into something else. It just lets you access it differently. To cast something as a particular type, that thing has to actually be that type.  E.g. if you assign a `Form` object to an `Object` variable then you could cast it as type `Form` because it is a `Form`.  If you assign a `String` and tried to cast as type `Form` though, it would fail, because a `String` is not a `Form`.

Comment: What you're suggesting doesn't make sense anyway.  `My.Forms` is a way to access the default instance of each form type in your project.  That means it provides access to one instance of each type and only one instance at all times.  You may or may not have displayed that one instance of each type and you may have displayed other instances.  If what you actually want is to access each form that is currently open then you need to use `My.Application.OpenForms`.  That is a collection so you can loop over and get types and `Text` properties and whatever else you like.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use a `String` in this way anyway?  When people want to identify things using `Strings` like this, it's often indicative of a design flaw.

Comment: Your code will not compile with Option Strict on which it should always be.

Comment: Computers have this annoying habit of doing exactly what you tell them to do. When you put something inside quotes " " it is a string. So you built a string with three parts and it was displayed in the label. The  Name property of Form1 is Form1. The Text property of a Form is what is displayed at the top of the window. Unless you change it, that will also be Form1.

Comment: I wanted to get the Text properties of a form dynamically. I Didn't know how to get this. What i did is entirely wrong and i knew it. Now i know what to do. There's a simple code to get the Text properties which is ' Me.Text ' Thank You all.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you need is the following code. But you need to create the equivalent of frmNameLabelControl in the same order in every form. For example to be the last label you created in every form

```
    Dim FormsCount As Integer = My.Application.OpenForms.Count
    Dim frmProperty As String
    Dim lblContrIndex As Integer = 0 ' Number of label creation in descending order

    For i As Integer = 0 To FormsCount - 1

        frmProperty = My.Application.OpenForms.Item(i).Text
        My.Application.OpenForms.Item(i).Controls.OfType(Of Label).ElementAt(lblContrIndex).Text = frmProperty

    Next
```

Comment: I wanted to get the Text properties of a form dynamically. I Didn't know how to get this. What i did is entirely wrong and i knew it. Now i know what to do. There's a simple code to get the Text properties which is ' Me.Text '

Thank You all.  

@andreas